# How do I copy projected results into another variable in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, types, linq-to-sql

The code below wont run, as it complains that I am trying to add a type Anon into a type of Clients. How can I store certain results in another variable after projecting them originally and having lost the original Type.

(PS. I have made my example simple but am actually dealing with a more complex case. Not projecting is not an option in my actual case. *Edited to provide clarification*.)

```
var clients = Clients.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("Mark"))
.Select(c => new {
    LastName = c.LastName.ToUpper(),
    c.DateAdded,
    c.FirstName,
})
.ToList();
var certainClients = new List<Clients> { };

foreach (var client in clients)
{
    if(client.DateAdded.Date < DateTime.Today) {
        certainClients.Add(client);
    }
}

certainClients.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

First. Instead of using an anon data type, use `Clients` datatype. As in effect you are creating `Clients` object -

```
var clients = Clients.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("Mark"))
              .Select(c => new Clients{
                       LastName = c.LastName.ToUpper(),
                       c.DateAdded,
                       c.FirstName,
 })
```

Second.  Create a list of `object` and assign whatever custom/anon data type to it -

```
var certainClients = new List<object> { };
```

Comment: Perfect! `new List<object> { };` works perfectly in my case. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to project to a custom business entity class.
This means that we actually define the class ourselves. For example.

```
 public class ClientEntity
    {
       public string LastName;
       public DateTime DateAdded;
        // etc for custom fields or properties you want
    }
```

Then we can simply project to our custom made class

```
var clients = Clients.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("Mark"))
              .Select(c => new ClientEntity{
                       LastName = c.LastName.ToUpper(),
                       DateAdded = c.DateAdded,
                       etc
 })
```

This way it avoids `List <object>` which is not type safe and doesn't need to be similar to the original client class for example if we want the length of the original name.